# JUnit Reads applicationContext.xml but claims <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/> does not exist

Tags: spring, junit

I created an STS Spring MVC Template application and wanted to wire in and test my Dao's using JUnit. The project loads fine in Tomcat Here is my servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<!--  JDBC Datasource Configuration Bean  -->
<beans:bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" /> 
    <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</beans:bean>
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

The context:property jdbc.properties loads fine until it gets read in by the @ContextConfiguration

Here is my JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml"})
public class ControllerTest{

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;
    private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private HomeController homeController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
       response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

       handlerAdapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHallo() throws Exception {

        request.setRequestURI("/");
        request.setMethod("GET");
        final ModelAndView mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response,
                   homeController);

       System.out.println("TEST "   + mav.getModelMap());

    }

}
```

**If I comment out the jdbc.properties file it works fine**

The error I am getting is:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Failed to load ApplicationContext**

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: **Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/jdbc.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist**

The project runs fine but JUnit cannot find the database properties .

**Here is what I have tried:**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>
```

Also

However, that causes Tomcat to throw an Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this because paths are not read the same way when using JUnit and Servlet container.
In fact when using Tomcat, the WEB-INF folder is placed under the root web application folder. And for this, using `/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties` will work fine.
But when using JUnit, this won't be the case, since you will be using your Maven project as directory structure.
One solution for this situation, would be to separate properties files used for JUnit tests (even if they are the same as production properties files) and place them under: `src/test/resources`.
Then in your Spring configs, use:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
```

By now, both under Tomcat and JUnit Spring should be able to find your files

Comment: Also copy your context file under src/main/resources folder

Comment: Is it correct that I use that `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>` wherein `jdbc.properties` is inside `src/main/resources` and I can just do `@Value()`???

Answer (score 0):

In your **spring** `applicationContext.xml` file, Please check

```
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.controller"/>
```

`component-scan` should not contain component which has `@Controller` annotation